# How to block 111 udp port via iptables?

Tags: iptables, tcp, udp, rpc

I've got an issue related to block 111 port only for `udp`. For `tcp` it was blocked without any problem. This port is used by application `rpcbind`. I test it via `netcat`. This is my iptables. It contains empty chain `FORWARD`, because I've removed all rules from it for easy understanding.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:sunrpc
2    DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:sunrpc

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DOCKER-OVERLAY  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER (0 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (0 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
2    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
3    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-OVERLAY (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

This port will be opened for set of server but they don't exist in iptables right now for easy understanding too.
What must I do for blocking 111 port over udp?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on how nice you want to be to the client, a possible solution can be:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp  --dport 111 -j DROP
```

or

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp  --dport 111 -j REJECT
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 2nd case works for me. But important thing. 1st case mustn't exists in chain. If to add it before 2nd case, than it will not work.

Comment: That's why there is an **OR** between lines. **DROP**, as name says, will drop the packet without reply. The client will fail with timeout. **REJECT** will be seen as **connection refused**.